# Set theory axioms exercise

Tags: functions, solution-verification

a)Prove that a "set of all sets" does not exist. [Hint: if $V$ is a set of all sets, consider $\{x\in\,V\,|\;x\notin x\}$.

b)Prove that for any set $A$, there is some $x\notin A$.

These exercises are from chapter 1, section 3 of Jech and Hrbacek's "Introduction to Set Theory." For some reason, I'm struggling to axiomatically show a). It seems b) will naturally follow course afterward, simply employing proof by contradiction, essentially making it part a).

a) Let $V$ be a set of all sets. In other words, $\forall x, x\in V$. Since $V$ is, by hypothesis, a set, then by comprehension schema axiom: for the property $\mathbf P(x)$ given by "$x\notin x$", there exists some set, $C$, such that $x\in C$ if and only if $x\in V$ and $\mathbf P(x)$. Now, if $V\in C$, this implies $V\in V$ and $V\notin V$, a clear contradiction. Hence, $V\notin C$. But by the definition of $C$, this, in turn, implies $\lnot \bigl(V\in V$ and $\mathbf P(V)\bigl)$, which means $V\notin V$ or $\lnot \mathbf P(V)$; in other words, $V\notin V$ or $V\in V$. Suppose $V\notin V$. Then, at the same time, by the definition of $V$, $V\in V$; a contradiction. Now suppose $V\in V$...? [can't seem to be able to reach contradiction from here]

Comment: Rather than asking if $V\in C$ or if $V\in V$ or similar... ask yourself if $C\in C$

Comment: For reference, this particular result that you are investigating is known in the literature as [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).  Knowing the name, you may be able to find dozens if not hundreds more explanations.

Comment: Thank you! That does, indeed, make things immensely simpler. I completed the proof of a). Now, for b):

Suppose, to the contrary, not. Then there exists some set, $A$, such that, for any (set) $x$, $x\in A$. [$A$, now, assumes the roll of $V$ from part a), and the problem is otherwise finished, yes?]

Comment: Effectively.  If you had assumed that there exists some $A$ such that there is no $x$ such that $x\notin A$ then $A$ would have to be the "universal set", which is the set of all sets discussed earlier (*or even larger if you have urelements in your set theory*) which we just showed couldn't exist.